# fill color from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have color table in my database. When page loads color id and color name and color should displayed in GridView.

datafield="color_Id" contains hex color value. I want to use that hex color code into the back color of the gridview table.

My code is:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="color_Id" HeaderText="Color Id"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="color" HeaderText="Color Name"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblColor" BackColor='<%# Eval("color_Id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

</columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put an # before the eval like this. Should work.

```
BackColor='#<%# Eval("color_Id") %>'
```

Comment: in my database color code has "#" symbol. like #FFF000. database retrieves '#FFF000' this type of data

Answer (score 0):

BackColor is a System.Drawing.Color property and not a string property.  I'm not certain what magic ASP.NET uses to convert BackColor="#FF00FF", but it doesn't work when you evaluate the string at runtime.

Use the following in your code behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim c As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblColor")
        If c IsNot Nothing Then
            c.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(e.Row.DataItem.color_ID)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I done it by referencing codes.

thanks for give little idea for jason.

these are the codes

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string colId="",colr="";
    colId = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
    colr = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;

    if (colId.Trim() != "Color Id" && colr.Trim() != "Color Name")
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtColor");
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colId);
        }
    }
}

<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" BackColor="Transparent">
    <columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="color_Id" HeaderText="Color Id"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="color" HeaderText="Color Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color">
            <ItemTemplate>
                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtColor" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

thank you for  view & give me a help  to overcome my problem.